# Cordova create new project error after update of node and npm

Tags: node.js, cordova, node-modules

[Click here to view error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFwT9.png)

Node.js version 4.2.1
npm version 3.3.3
cordova version 5.3.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like you have been caught by a mis-behaving application that is relying on the folder structure inside npm.  Downgrade your npm to the latest 2.x by using:

```
npm install -g npm@2
```

This will produce the old semantics of npm (which is what your error message showed).  There is an open bug against this issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-9687

Comment: Thanks fro your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can also downgrade to npm 3.0.0 its works

npm install -g npm@3.0.0